# Load an assembly that's not in the GAC or bin directory of a web application by using assembly name, not the path

Tags: c#, asp.net, assemblies

I have a dll which is in directory xyz. Is there a way to load that dll without actually specifying the path?
I know I could load it simply by specifying the path to the dll, [but then I bumped into a pretty annoying issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665987/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-mytype-but-this-dictionar) that forces me to copy that dll to my applications bin directory and load it using its name.
I would prefer though to not have that dll in the bin directory. So is there a way to load an assembly using its name which is actually not located in the GAC or bin directory?
Is there something I can do to have my web application scan additional directories for an assembly?

Comment: Maybe you may find this [useful](http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=713)

Comment: I gave all of you who mentioned the probing web.config element a +1.. Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look into assembly probing

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="bin;bin2\subbin;bin3"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

and also check here: How the runtime locates assemblies: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15hyw9x3(v=VS.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15hyw9x3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can specify in you app.config where to look for assemblies.

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="bin;bin2\subbin;bin3"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

- By using the `Probing` Element.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`probing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx) element in your web.config.
I doubt however, that this resolves your problem in the other question.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative approach to the config based answers, you can register for the [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx).

This gives you a chance to run some code when assembly resolution fails, so you can try to rectify the problem at runtime (for example you could run a recursive directory search for the dll if you're feeling saucy).

This could be more flexible than using configuration, at the expense of some extra complexity.