# Resolve caste windsor failing

Tags: castle-windsor

Recently upgraded to version 3.2.1 of castle windsor and receiving an error when attempting to resolve a service that previously didn't occur in version 3.0 of the windsor framework.

```
IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
```

The following code no longer works

```
// Throws component not found exception
 InstallerHelper.ProcessAssembliesInBinDirectory(
            assembly => container.Register(
                Classes
                    .FromAssembly(assembly)
                    .BasedOn<IWindsorInstaller>()
                    .WithService.FromInterface()
                    .LifestyleSingleton()
                            ));

var installers = container.ResolveAll<IWindsorInstaller>();
container.Install(installers);
// Fails here, is it related to a hashcode mismatch in SimpleTypeEqualityComparer?
var credentialCache = container.Resolve<ICredentialCache>()

// works fine if explicity install installers individually
container.Install(new CredentialsInstaller());
var credentialCache = container.Resolve<ICredentialCache>()
```

Where ProcessAssembliesInBinDir is:

```
 public static void ProcessAssembliesInBinDirectory(Action<Assembly> action)
    {
        var directoryName = GetDirectoryName();

        foreach (var dll in Directory.GetFiles(directoryName, "*.dll"))
        {
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(dll);
            if (!IgnoreList.Any(x=>fileInfo.Name.StartsWith(x)))
            {
                var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dll);
                action(assembly);
            }
        }
    }
```

Where credential installer is:

```
public class CredentialsInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
           container.Register(
            Component.For<ICredentidalCache>()
                     .ImplementedBy<CredentidalCache>()
                     .LifestyleSingleton()
            );
            // This works fine
            var credentialCache = container.Resolve<ICredentialCache>()
    }
}
```

Class implementation

```
public interface ICredentidalCache    {}
public class CredentidalCache : ICredentidalCache{}
```

- This is being run from an MVC application
- version 4.5 of the .net framework
- the credential installer lives inside another assembly, referenced by the website
- using the Windsor source, the successful attempt to resolve occurs when the typeof(ICredentialCache).GetHashCode() is the same as what has been registered. For some reason when returning out of the installer the hashcode has changed for the type. Putting a debug line inside SimpleTypeEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(Type obj) shows that hashcodes are different for the same Type.
- inspecting the container inside the debugger shows the ICredentialCache successfully installed.

**Edit**
Manage to move forward by manually registering installers, ie. not relying on the `resolve<IwindsorInstaller>()` and use `container.install(new Installer(), ...)`. If i find out more I'll update the SO question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the InstallerHelper and how it goes about loading an assembly. This SO post pointed me in the right direction,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6675227/564957

essentially the way the assembly was loaded was failing using Assembly.LoadFile(string fileName) was causing the problem, changing this to be Assembly.Load(string assemblyName) rectified the issue.

[@Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) does a good job explaining

> [when] loading an assembly by its path, and one via loading the same
>   assembly by its assembly name...  reflection will
>   consider types from the two loadings of the same assembly to be
>   different types. Any assembly loaded from its path is considered to be
>   distinct from an assembly loaded by its assembly name.

Comment: Suzanne Cook wrote a bunch of blog posts ten years ago about how this all works; check out her blog if you want more details. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
public sealed class AppServiceFactory
{
...
 public T Create<T>()
 {
     return (T)container.Resolve(typeof(T));
 }
...
}


AppServiceFactory.Instance.Create<IYourService>();
```

Comment: @irb Gave it a go, but unfortunately didn't solve my problem.